# subscriberCellularProvider was deprecated in iOS 12.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, cellular-network, carrier

I'm trying to make a list carrier with subscriberCellularProvider. But I got one problem which is "**'subscriberCellularProvider' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Replaced by serviceSubscriberCellularProviders**"

I'm using XCode 11.4.1 and iOS 13. Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It is recommending to use `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` instead of  `subscriberCellularProvider `

Answer (score 14):

The warning is telling you that you should use `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` instead, that returns an optional dictionary of type `[String : CTCarrier]?`. Probably is added to support devices with multiple sim (eg. iPhone XR with SIM + eSIM)

I can't figure out which key to use with the dictionary, in my case (iPhone 8) I have only one object with key `0000000100000001` so I get the carrier with:

`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?["0000000100000001"]`

You could try with:

`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value`

but obviously there’s not guarantee that you will get the same info between different executions of your app.

I couldn't find any further documentation about it

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 6):

**'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
Replace 'subscriberCellularProvider' with 'serviceSubscriberCellularProviders'**

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>


CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];

NSDictionary<NSString *, CTCarrier *> *providers= [networkInfo serviceSubscriberCellularProviders];
                
CTCarrier *carrier = providers.allValues.firstObject;
                
NSString* isoCountryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
                
NSString* mobileNetworkCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode;
                
NSString* mobileCountryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode;
                
NSString* carrierName = carrier.carrierName;
```

Comment: Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Comment: Is this a solution you never explained where to write this?

Comment: @RehanAliKhan this solution is relevant to the above question asked. I didn't get the point? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

@Andr3a88 's answer is not precise. For iPhone with 2 SIM cards `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` returns at least 2 elements one of them may have carrier as this

```
CTCarrier (0x283d8e940) {
    Carrier name: [<nil>]
    Mobile Country Code: [<nil>]
    Mobile Network Code:[<nil>]
    ISO Country Code:[<nil>]
    Allows VOIP? [YES]
```

for non-used eSIM I guess.

So it is preferable to check if carrier name is not NIL

```
let netInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = netInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.filter({ $0.value.carrierName != nil }).first?.value
```